# Remove all files in folder apart from one using OS X Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal

I would like to remove the whole content of a folder, apart from one file. The problem is can't copy the file to another folder and then back to the first folder, because then the application doesn't accepts the file, so the one file must stay in the folder.

Exists there a command like I described?

Answer (score 4):

I would go about it like this:

```
find . ! -name <filename> -delete
```

for this to work with folders, you have to replace the `delete` with an `exec rm -r`

```
find . ! -name <filename> -exec rm -rv {} \;
```

This breaks down to

`find` = find

`.` = in current working directory, you can replace `.` with a path, like `~/Documents/`

`!` = not

`-name` = name

`<filename>` = file

`-exec` = execute

`rm -rv` = verbose remove

`{}` = results of the find

`\;` = close the execution

Find all files and folders in your working folder, that **do not** have the name `filename` and then execute the remove command on the results.

You should do a dry run without the delete option, first:

```
find . ! -name <filename>
```

This command gives you a list of all files and folders in your working directory that are not named `<filename>`. Adding `-delete` or `-exec rm -rv {} \;`, will delete this files and folder (the `exec` version).

---

You could also use

```
rm -v [^filename]
```

for folders add `-r`

```
rm -rv [^filename]
```

Somehow I feel more comfortable using the `find` option. Mainly because you can do a dry run. Either way I would start with a dummy folder and try both options.

Comment: Works that version also with folders? EDIT: With `find . ! -name <filename>` I'm getting a long list in Terminal.

Comment: `find . ! -name <filename>` gives you all files (and folders) in your current folder.

As about deletion of folders: I changed my answer to also delete folders.

Comment: The surroundings changed ... Now I'm having a folder and their content must stay. Is that possible with `find`?

Answer (score 0):

For being really sure about this, you could use find to create a deletion shellscript with "rm" commands:

```
find . ! -name "<filename>" -exec echo "rm -rf {}" >> /tmp/rm.sh \;
```

Delete every line in the shellscript /tmp/rm.sh you do not like, then execute it by

```
bash /tmp/rm.sh
```

But be careful - find also finds directories and "rm -rf" would then delete them recursively as well! Narrow down your search by telling find the filetype to search for:

```
find . ! -name "<filename>" -type <filetype> -exec echo "rm -rf {}" >> /tmp/rm.sh \;
```

Have fun! :-)

Comment: Is there a way to add a path to the command line so that I get only results from the path?

Comment: Replace the "." with your path.


    find <your path> ! -name "<filename>" -type <filetype> -exec echo "rm -rf {}" >> /tmp/rm.sh \;

Comment: Is it easier with `ls`? If I copy the files with `cp` the files are outside of their folders.